# Record syntax and sum types

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I have this question about sum types in Haskell.

I'd like to create a sum type which is comprised of two or more other types, and each of the types may contain multiple fields. A trivial example would be like this:

```
data T3 = T1 { a :: Int, b :: Float} | T2 { x :: Char } deriving (Show)
```

In my understanding, `T1` and `T2` are data constructors which use record syntax. It seems that the definition of `T3` will grow as the number of fields in `T1` or `T2` increases. My question is that how to practically handle these sum type constructors if the number of fields are large? Or, is it a good idea to mix sum type with record syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you actually want: if you have a large number of fields you still have to write them all... what would you what to do instead? Also, fields and sum types do not play terribly well together since e.g. `a :: T3 -> Int` is partial, and will crash your program as soon as you mistakenly feed a `T2 'c'` value to it. (OTOH, if fields are only used in patterns, then they are safe.)

Comment: "how to handle": What actual problem are you having? That the definition looks too big? You have to repeat yourself too much? Records aren't extensible? Something else?

Comment: ... avoid writing all data constructors on one line?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear in my question. My concern is that since T1 and T2 are embedded in T3, T3 might get bloated if T1 or T2 are complex. I am looking for a way to "decouple" T1 and T2 from T3 such that the internals of T1 and T2 can be defined separately. @leftaroundabout showed a solution with `T3_1` and `T3_2` below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't quite understand what concerns you have, but to answer the question in the last line: *no*, it is rather not a good idea to mix sum types with record syntax. Records in general remain a bit of a weak spot of the Haskell language; they don't handle scoping very well at all. It's usually fine as long as you just have some seperate types with different record labels, but as soon as sum types or name clashes come in it gets rather nasty.

In particular, Haskell permits you to use a record field accessor of the `T1` constructor for any value of type `T3` – `print $ a (T2 'x')` will compile without warnings, but give a rather hard to foresee error at runtime.

In your example, it fortunately looks like you can easily avoid that kind of trouble:

```
data T3 = T3_1 T1 | T3_2 T2
           deriving (Show)
data T1 = T1 { a :: Int
             , b :: Float}
           deriving (Show)
data T2 = T2 { x :: Char }
           deriving (Show)
```

Now, any deconstruction you could write will be properly typechecked to make sense.

And such a structure of meaningful, small specialised sub-types<sup>†</sup> is generally better to handle than a single monolithic type, especially if you have many functions that really deal only with part of the data structure.

The flip side is that it gets quadratically tedious to unwrap the layers of constructors, but that's fortunately a solved problem now: [lens libraries](http://lens.github.io/) allow you to compose accessor/modifiers very neatly.

Speaking of solved problems: [Nikita Volkov](https://nikita-volkov.github.io/record/) has come up with a really nice concept for entirely replacing the problem-ridden record syntax.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Um... actually these aren't subtypes in any proper sense of the word, but you get what I mean.</sub>