# Instance Eq for data type with several sub-fields

Tags: haskell

I have a data type with several sub-fields and would like to implement the `instance Eq` class *simultaneously*.

The code is the following :

```
data Expression 
                = Variable  {
                            name            ::  String,
                            number          ::  Double,
                            exponentVal     ::  Double 
                            }
                |   Numeric Double
                |   CanonicalForm [Expression]
    deriving Show 

instance Eq Expression where
    someone == another = name someone == name another
    someone == another = exponentVal someone == exponentVal another
```

How could I modify the `instance Eq` class so that when I compare two variables the comparison evaluates both the `name` field and the `exponentVal` field ?

Comment: Start with a simpler data type and work your way up to a more complex type.

Comment: What happens in `Variable "" 1 1 == Numeric 1`? What happens in `name (Numeric 1)`?

Comment: People usually recommend not mixing Sum and Record types, see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652243/record-syntax-and-sum-types

Comment: What does "simultaneously" mean here? What's wrong with the instance generated by `deriving (Show, Eq)`?

Answer (score 3):

Use pattern matching in your `==` definition

```hs
instance Eq Expression where
    Variable a b c == Variable a' b' c = a == a' && b == b' && c == c'
    -- other 2 cases
    _ == _ = False
```

Or just use `deriving Eq` as already pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

For comparing two `Variable` values, you just need to combine the two field comparisons with `&&`.

```
instance Eq Expression where
    someone == another = name someone == name another && exponentVal someone == exponentVal another
```

However, this ignores the possibility that either argument might not *be* a `Variable`. You should use pattern matching.

```
instance Eq Expression where
    Variable n1 _ v1 == Variable n2 _ v2 = n1 == n2 && v1 == v2
    Number n1 == Number n2 = n1 == n2
    CanonicalForm es1 == CanonicalForm es2 = ...  -- appropriate definition here
    _ == _ = False
```

In the above, I've assumed that if the data constructors don't match, the expressions are not equal.